# How to move image with low values?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

The problem is simple: I want to move (and later, be able to rotate) an image. For example, every time i press the right arrow on my keyboard, i want the image to move 0.12 pixels to the right, and every time i press the left arrow key, i want the image to move 0.12 pixels to the left.

Now, I have multiple solutions for this:
1) simply add the incremental value, i.e.:

```
image.x += 0.12;
```

this is of course assuming that we're going to the right.

2) i multiplicate the value of a single increment by the times i already went into this particular direction + 1, like this:

```
var result:Number = 0.12 * (numberOfTimesWentRight+1);
image.x = result;
```

Both of these approaches work but produce similiar, yet subtly different, results. If we add some kind of button component that simply resets the x and y coordinates of the image, you will see that with the first approach the numbers don't add up correctly.
it goes from .12, .24, .359999, .475 etc.

But with the second approach it works well. (It's pretty obvious as to why though, it seems like += operations with Numbers are not really precise).

Why not use the second approach then? Well, i want to rotate the image as well. This will work for the first attempt, but after that the image will jump around. Why? In the second approach we never took the original position of the image in account. So if the origin-point shifts a bit down or up because you rotated your image, and THEN you try to move the image again: it will move to the same position as if you hadn't rotated before.

Alright, to make this short:
How can i reliably move, scale and rotate images for 1/10 of a pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: I don't know! You're fighting with floating point math!

Luckily, I have a workaround, if you don't mind.

You store the location (x and y) of the image in a separate variable... at a larger scale. Such as 100x. So `123.45` becomes `12345`, and you then divide by 100 to set the attribute that flash uses to display.

Yes, there are limits to number sizes too, but if you're willing to accept some error rate, and the fact that you'll be limited to, I dunno, a million pixels in each direction, you can fit it in a regular int. The only rounding error you will encounter will be a single rounding error when you divide by 100 (or the factor you used). So instead of the compound rounding error which you described (`0.12 * 4 = 0.475`), you should see things like `0.47999999`. Which doesn't matter because it's, well, so small.

Comment: I see. I tried to do that as well, (multiplicating then dividing by 100) but the result still wasn't reliable enough. I'll try it again though, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Have you tried to see what numbers you get from the multiplied number? `0.12 * 100` should be 12, not 11.99. Else the problem just stays. If that happens you might have to express all your constants at a 100x scale.

Comment: I tried this approach again today, and now it works. Seems like i was missing a step the last time. I used both yours and divillysausages advice, keeping a variable to do the work on, multiply and divice by a factor. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Pimgd answer a bit, you're probably hitting a floating point error (multiple `+=`'s will exaggerate the error more than one `*=`'s) - `Numbers` in Flash are 53-bit precision.

There's also another thing to keep in mind, which is probably playing a bigger role with such small movement values; Flash positions all objects using `twips`, which is roughly about `1/20th` of a pixel, or `0.05`, so all values are rounded to this. When you say `image.x += 0.12`, it's actually the equivalent of `image.x += 0.10`, hence which the different becomes apparent; you're losing `0.02` of a pixel with every move.

You should be able to get around it by moving to another scale, as @Pimgd says, or just storing your position separately - i.e. work from a property `_x` rather than `image.x` so you're not losing that precision everytime:

```
this._x += 0.12;
image.x = this._x;
```